# Vscode Code Spell Checker not working on typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I find it difficult to make this VsCode extension `Code Spell Checker` to work on m typescript files.

However, it works fine on other files and even the compiled javascript files produced by the typescript are being validated by the extension.

Searching online, I discovered that some people have the same issue, but no solution has been provided.

I have also tried setting the `C Spell: Enable Filetypes` to `*` and as well adding `ts` to `C Spell: Enabled Language Ids` and still got no luck on this

Please can someone point me to what can be done to ensure that `Code Spell Checker` works with my typescript files?

Comment: So it just doesn't run at all for any `*.ts` file?  I just installed the extension and it works by default for me in TS files.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Yes, though there was a time it worked but for a long time now it never worked again for me

Comment: Maybe just try removing and and then re-installing it?

Comment: "_Searching online, I discovered that some people have the same issue, but no solution has been provided._" links please :) Please also add version info of your VS Code and spell checker extension. Provide some example texts of things you expect to see it complain about, but it doesn't. Also, what do you see when you click the spell checker indicator in the bottom right?

Comment: @FiniteLooper Sometimes it work and sometime it do not work, I have to access the bundled js files and check for the grammer